# finding distinct elements in a column without using keyword DISTINCT in sql

Tags: sql

in a Table there is a single attribute(column).it contains numbers.Some are repeated(2 or 3 and so on times) and some appears only one time.write as many queries to output all the numbers only once(apart from using distinct in SQL query).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you don't need the HAVING clause:

```
SELECT v1
FROM ztable
GROUP by v1
        ;
```

The HAVING clause will make things worse: it would only list the values that occur only once!

Comment: Rereading the question, this is the **only** answer so far that actually does what OP asks.

Comment: @Lieven - I think we all incorrectly read "output all the numbers only once" as being "output all the numbers that only occur once"!

Comment: Well, not *all*, but most of you did ;-)

Comment: @MartinSmith - True. I was typing a comment to this answer, telling why it was wrong until I realised it was actually right <g>. Your answer works too though if you remove the except clause. I have voted to undelete it.

Comment: @Lieven - Now I've read the question properly it is basically a dupe of the [OP's other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11205578/73226) anyway.

Comment: @MartinSmith: Now that I look at it, my answer is actually a dupe of your first option there, and yours was a dupe of a_horse_with_no_name's answer there.

Answer (score 3):

```
select column from table group by column;
```

**EDIT :** Actually, `and some appears only one time.write as many queries to output all the numbers only once.` this made me think about the once occurred result.

Answer (score 1):

`GROUP BY` the column and use `HAVING`

```
select columname
from tablename
group by columnname
having count(columnname) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

since there is only 1 column in the table, so there is no need to put any having clause as it will affect the performance for large volume of data (say 1,000,000)

so try something like

select col
from tbl
group by col