# List distinct tuples in a table(SQL query)(10 ways)

Tags: sql, database

What are the different ways of listing **distinct tuples** in a table, the original  question from **GOLDMAN SACHS** says to list 10 different ways one such way is using **DISTINCT** . Can anybody help me with more..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's four.

`GROUP BY <all_columns>`

`SELECT * FROM T INTERSECT SELECT * FROM T`

`SELECT * FROM T UNION SELECT * FROM T`

`SELECT * FROM T EXCEPT SELECT * FROM T WHERE 1 = 0`

Comment: `select distinct ...` is the obvious one :)

Comment: @juergend - Yep. That one's given in the question though!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another one (ANSI SQL)

```
select *
from (
    select t.*,
           row_number() over (partition by <all_columns>) as rn
    from t
) t
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Set @row:=0; 
select colname from (select colname,@row:=@row+1 as Row from tablename group by colname) as abc where Row>0;
```

This is another method by giving row names to the entries.

Answer (score 0):

1   Using Count and Group By:

```
select f1,f2,count(*) from sample_table 
group by f1,f2 
having count(*) = 1;
```

2  using Common Table Expression:

```
;WITH CTE (Col1,Col2,Col3,DuplicateCount)
AS
(
SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Col1,Col2,Col3 ORDER BY Col1) AS DuplicateCount
FROM MyTable)
Select * from CTE Where DuplicateCount=1
```